# Подготовка системы к программированию на Java

Tags: java, классы

Здравствуйте.
Решил начать изучать Java. В данный момент нахожусь на этапе установки оной. Скачал и установил `jdk-7u10-windows-i586`. В видео уроках (там win xp, у меня 7) показано, что в переменных среды нужно к Patch добавить путь до папки `bin` установленного Java и в `CLASSPATH` дописать " ;. ".
Собственно тут проблема и началась: у меня нету этого самого `CLASSPATH`. Тут так-же пишут, что его нужно создать вручную, но в виде оуроке в нём был прописан ещё некий путь, после которого и ставится точка. Какой путь прописывать мне, если это необходимо и необходимо ли?
Прошу прощения за ламерство.

Comment: разобратся как запускать с командной строчки это конечно полезное дело но лучше это же время потратить на освоение IDE (среды разработки). что позитивно скажется на скорости написания кода и прогреса в обучении

Comment: @jmu всё почти правильно (как говорят математики -- с точностью до наоборот).

Comment: за 8 лет работы с java реальная необходимость запускать компиляцию из командной строчки раза 3 (в демонстрационных целях) и еще раза 2 с целью самообучения. Запускать програму на выполнение аналогичным образом понадобилось при сдаче курсовой и вот на текущем проэкте (регулярно). 

Это статистика за 8 лет что я работаю с java. Я - практик, громкие фразы псевдонаполненные смыслом меня не смогут убедить. Факты в студию сэр! Расскажите, сколько жизней спасло ваше умение компилировать, запускать java программы из командной строки. Сколько миллионов строк кода вы написали без IDE? А мы послушаем...

Comment: @jmu Увы, на java не пишу вообще. Но примеры тех, кто полагается на IDE с другими языками, здесь регулярно всплывают.

Читал, что лучшей IDEй для java является JDK. Это правда?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA же, и да в реальной жизни не особо полезный скилл работать с командной строкой (хотя все-таки иногда нужно было, но очень редко и не критично)

Answer (score 4):

Можно обойтись и без объявления `CLASSPATH` в виде переменной среды. Можно (и вообще то нужно) передавать `CLASSPATH` компилятору и JVM непосредственно в ходе исполнения. Типа:

```
javac -classpath <path> Test.java
```

Но если так уж надо, то идите *Control Panel->System Properties->Environment Variables* и заводите переменную `CLASSPATH` и вводите туда `.;` - то есть в `CLASSPATH` по умолчанию всегда будет включен текущий каталог.

**P.S.** Если у вас 64-х битная система установите оба JDK для 32-х и 64-х бит